# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect (JWT-SpringBoot-OAUTH-Spring Security))

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have this integration Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ResourceServerApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class AuthenticationClaimsIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenStore tokenStore;

    @Test
    public void whenTokenDontContainIssuer_thenSuccess() {
        final String tokenValue = obtainAccessToken("clientId", "root", "");
        final OAuth2Authentication auth = tokenStore.readAuthentication(tokenValue);
        System.out.println(tokenValue);
        System.out.println(auth);
        assertTrue(auth.isAuthenticated());
        System.out.println(auth.getDetails());

        Map<String, Object> details = (Map<String, Object>) auth.getDetails();
        assertTrue(details.containsKey("organization"));
        System.out.println(details.get("organization"));
    }

    private String obtainAccessToken(String clientId, String username, String password) {
        final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("grant_type", "password");
        params.put("client_id", clientId);
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
        final Response response = RestAssured.given()
            .auth()
            .preemptive()
            .basic(clientId, "secret")
            .and()
            .with()
            .params(params)
            .when()
            .post("http://localhost:8081/skillsws/oauth/token");
        return response.jsonPath()
            .getString("access_token");
    }

}
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
        at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1974)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.post(HTTPBuilder.java:341)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$post$2.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1159)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:30)
        at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73)
        at com.jayway.restassured.filter.time.TimingFilter.filter(TimingFilter.java:56)
        at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:73)
        at com.jayway.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1596)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:164)
        at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at fr.dawan.skillsws.tests.AuthenticationClaimsIntegrationTest.obtainAccessToken(AuthenticationClaimsIntegrationTest.java:57)
        at fr.dawan.skillsws.tests.AuthenticationClaimsIntegrationTest.whenTokenDontContainIssuer_thenSuccess(AuthenticationClaimsIntegrationTest.java:31)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

After I breezed though similar errors at SO, I thought it's probably a server port problem, and so I added the following code to "pre-set" the port with a number different from the 8080 used by the app:

```
@LocalServerPort
private int port;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    RestAssured.port = port;
}
```

Still the connection is still inaccessible. Is there something I'm overlooking here?

Comment: Since you configured the port, I think you should not specify the whole URL `http://localhost:8081/skillsws/oauth/token`, just the path you want to test, which is probably `/oauth/token`. Can you try it?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another errors now, but they have nothing to do with this one Could you please add your comment as an answer so I can upvote it and mark it as the correct answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you configured the port in the `setUp()` method, you should not specify the whole URL `http://localhost:8081/skillsws/oauth/token` when creating the request - use just the path you want to test (without a context path), which is probably `/oauth/token`.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.